# Python get info from API / Oauth Authentication

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, python-requests

that is my first try with an API, said API being called OPS.
I would like to get information using the API (OAuth 2) within my python code.

The ressource URL is :
[http://ops.epo.org/3.2/rest-services/register/{publication}/{EPODOC}/{EP2814089}/biblio](http://%20http://ops.epo.org/3.2/rest-services/register/%7Bpublication%7D/%7BEPODOC%7D/%7BEP2814089%7D/biblio)

I also received :

***Consumer Key: O220VlTQqAmodifiedsf0YeqgM6c***

***Consumer Secret Key: swWmodified3edjORU***

The documentation states that:

OPS uses the OAuth framework for Authentication and Authorization. At this point in
time, only the “Client Credentials” flow is supported using a Consumer key and
Consumer secret.

The actual steps to follow are:

**Step 1:** Client converts Consumer key and Consumer secret to
Base64Encode(Consumer key:Consumer secret).
This should be done programmatically using the language you are developing the client
application in. For the purposes of this example, a public website was used to perform
this conversion.
By entering the colon separated Client credentials, an encoded response is generated.
This response is then be used for basic Authentication.

**Step 2:** Client requests an access token using Basic Authentication, supplying its
Consumer key and Consumer secret with base64Encoding over encrypted HTTPS
connection:

[image]

OPS authenticates the client credentials passed in the Authorization header using basic
authentication method.
If credentials are valid, OPS responds with a valid access token.

Step 3: Client accesses OPS resources with access token in authorization header
(bearer tokens) over encrypted HTTPS connection

[image]

I tried a few samples of code with requests but, until now, nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client credentials flow is described in the OAuth2 [RFC-6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4). The client id and secret are base64 encoded in a Basic authentication scheme as described in [RFC-7617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617)

You should be able to get a token using Python code like:

```
import requests
import base64

url = 'https://ops.epo.org/3.2/auth/accesstoken'
data = {"grant_type": "client_credentials"}

creds = base64.b64encode("O220VlTQqAmodifiedsf0YeqgM6c:swWmodified3edjORU".encode())
headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + creds.decode('UTF-8'), 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)

access_token = response.json()["access_token"]
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the previous response I can obtain a token. (Thanks a lot for your answer)

So I tried :

```
myUrl = 'http://ops.epo.org/3.2/rest-services/register/publication/EPODOC/EP2814089/biblio'

header = {'PRIVATE-TOKEN': myToken}
response = requests.get(myUrl, headers=header)
print(response.text)
```

but I obtained a 403 error.

I finally got a specific library to do the job :

[EPO OPS Library](https://pypi.org/project/python-epo-ops-client)

But I still don't know how to do it on my own...

Comment: Replace `header = {'PRIVATE-TOKEN': myToken}` with `header = {'Authorization': "Bearer " + myToken}`